# Is the description of the site appropriate?

Tags: discussion

The short description next to the philosophy site reads..

> For those interested in logical reasoning.

Isn't this a somewhat limiting description of philosophy with a strong analytical bias?

Comment: This comes up every now and then. I think it's a good idea, I will contact the SE team about this. I'll let you know.

Comment: This is done now, thanks!

Comment: @Keelan I'm still seeing the old description, is there a time lag?  And what did we change it to?

Comment: @ChrisSunami I also didn't see a change yet. There could be a time lag, but not this big. I pinged Jon Ericson about it, but haven't heard back yet. The idea was to change it to the suggestion [here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/285/2953), "For those interested in the study of the fundamental nature of knowledge, reality, and existence."

Comment: @ChrisSunami it has been changed now.